# Mercurial commands for developer

Tags: mercurial, merge, commit, head

What are the commands the developer must know in mercurial SCVS ultimately? apart from commit,pull data,push,clone?
and
I am always collapsing heads and branches fault in mercurial? How will you handle these knda situation?

Comment: As I am newbie to hg and well i have heared of git? just i want suggestion to choose?

Comment: If you're just choosing a VCS to store stuff locally, both Hg and Git are fine choices. If you're working on someone else's project you'll use whatever they set it up with, and if you do that a lot you'll probably need to learn both. If you want to put your code online, Github is spectacular, and there is not a great Hg equivalent, so you might use Git (Github is the main reason I default to Git; otherwise Git and Hg are pretty even, feature and speed wise).

Comment: There's a long list of commands, and an even longer list of ways to use them and appropriate and not appropriate usage. This type of question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow, however, due to its openness, and I'm closing it. There's plenty of tutorials out on the net for Mercurial users, but if you have a specific question, like "how to do X with Mercurial", feel free to ask that question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best source is [here](http://hginit.com/).

Answer (score 1):

the most useful command for you is

```
$ hg help
```